# Aligning polynomial expansion

Tags: align, alignment, alignat

I'm trying to expand a polynomial in such a way that coefficients of the same degree are aligned, like so

```
\begin{alignat*}{6}
f(t)
&={} (t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 +2(t + 1) + 1\\
&={} &t^4 &{}+{} &4t^3 &{}+{} &6t^2 &{}+{} &4t &{}+{} &1\\
&    &    &{}-{} &t^3  &{}-{} &3t^2 &{}-{} &3t &{}-{} &1\\
&    &    &      &     &      &     &{}+{} &2t &{}+{} &2\\
&    &    &      &     &      &     &      &   &{}+{} &1
\end{alignat*}
```

However, this renders the following
[image]
while the goal would be that those lines from the second onwards would be aligned with the first.
I understand that this is because I don't have enough `&` in the first line, but it seems impossible to put some in the exact location to have this right.

Perhaps a different align environment would be better?
I liked this one because I could align that expansion by coefficients, but another that would give the right result would be fine.
Or maybe if some trick can be added to the above.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses an 11-column `array` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}    % for '\mathrlap' macro    
\usepackage{array}        % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for binary and relational operators
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\displaystyle}r} % automatic displaystyle math mode
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\displaystyle}l} % automatic displaystyle math mode
\usepackage{booktabs}          % for '\midrule' and '\addlinespace' macros
\begin{document}

\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
\begin{array}{ R *{5}{CR} } % 11 columns in all
f(t) &=& \multicolumn{9}{L}{\mathrlap{(t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 + 2(t + 1) + 1}} \\
\addlinespace
     &=&       t^4 &+&      4t^3 &+& 6t^2 &+&       4t &+& 1 \\
     & &           &-&       t^3 &-& 3t^2 &-&       3t &-& 1 \\
     & &           & &           & &      &+&       2t &+& 2 \\
     & &           & &           & &      & &          &+& 1 \\
\midrule % optional
f(t) &=&       t^4 &+&      3t^3 &+& 3t^2 &+&       3t &+& 3 % optional
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems you understood the goal of the alignment was to make it easy to sum the lines, but I didn't want the first line to be aligned with the others (just on left, while the other aligned by coefficient as you did). It's another approach from which I might learn something, but even if others might find it senseless, I actually was able to do precisely what I wanted and it's in the answer I gave. (+1) anyway, and sorry if I was not clear enough in the post.

Comment: @amrsa - Many thanks for clarifying your formatting objective. I've updated my anwer to reflect this additional piece of information.

Comment: Oh yes, that it! Unfortunately, I can't upvote it twice :) But I think I will accept this one, since mine one still has some nitpicking problems

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
f(t)
= (t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 +2(t + 1) + 1&\\
= t^4 + 4t^3 + 6t^2 + 4t + 1&\\
- t^3  - 3t^2 - 3t - 1&\\
{}+ 2t + 2&\\
{}+  1&
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: The second one is about right (+1). I would prefer with the lines 2 to 5 shifted to the left so that the equal signs would be aligned, but this is ok. Probably I will accept it, if other doesn't appear doing exactly what I'd want.

Comment: @amrsa I do not think I am right but I tried, I edited post, chect it, is it correct?

Comment: No, the first version (which use to be the second) is correct, although not precisely what I wanted; the second version has too many `=` signs! It was like the first, but with those lines shifted to the left, but it's not very important.

Comment: Ok, I will just live one (almost correct version)

Comment: In the final two lines, the first `+` symbol is treated as a unary rather than as a binary operator. This formatting issue could be fixed by prefixing `{}` (an "empty math atom") to the `+` symbols in question.

Comment: @Mico thank You, edited

Answer (score 6):

Nest `array` inside `align`, which is simpler than using `alignedat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
f(t)
&= (t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 +2(t + 1) + 1 \\
&= \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
   \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
   \begin{array}[t]{*{4}{r >{{}}c<{{}}}r}
   t^4 &+& 4t^3 &+& 6t^2 &+& 4t &+& 1 \\
       &-&  t^3 &-& 3t^2 &-& 3t &-& 1 \\
       & &      & &      &+& 2t &+& 2 \\
       & &      & &      & &    &+& 1
   \end{array} \\
&= t^4+3t^3+3t^2+3t+3
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative approach with `IEEEeqnarray`. We just need a “phantom column”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{r C r C r C r C r C r l}
f(t)
&=& \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{10}{l}{(t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 +2(t + 1) + 1} \\
&=& t^4 &+& 4t^3 &+& 6t^2 &+& 4t &+& 1 \\
& &     &-&  t^3 &-& 3t^2 &-& 3t &-& 1 \\
& &     & &      & &      &+& 2t &+& 2 \\
& &     & &      & &      & &    &+& 1 \\
&=& \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{10}{l}{t^4+3t^3+3t^2+3t+3}
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks (+1). I think that once I could produce the result I wanted it became clear to others and everybody can now produce it with a different approach. My choice of words must have been a very poor one. It's always good to learn different ways. For example, if in one of the lines there were not monomials of consecutive exponents, my approach wouldn't work, and so others like this one which are more structured are very useful.

Comment: @amrsa I added a perhaps simpler approach.

Comment: Yes it seems simpler. Thanks again!

Comment: +1. :-) For the second solution, which uses an `array`, you may want to use display-style math in the `r` columns, so that the exponents are placed at the same heights as in the first and last row (which use displaystyle-math by default). OK, I'll admit that very few people might ever notice this...

Answer (score 4):

Here is another possibility.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1.2pt}
$\begin{NiceArray}{l*{5}{cr}}
  f(t)
    &=& \Block[l]{1-9}{(t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 +2(t + 1) + 1} \\
    &=& t^4 &+& 4t^3 &+& 6t^2 &+& 4t &+& 1 \\
    & &     &-& t^3  &-& 3t^2 &-& 3t &-& 1 \\
    & &     & &      & &      & & 2t &+& 2 \\
    & &     & &      & &      & &    &+& 1 \\
    &=& t^4 &+& 3t^3 &+& 3t^2 &+& 3t &+& 3
  \CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray, dashed,
          shorten >= 1mm,
          shorten <= 1mm] 
      (2-2.south)
      to
      (6-2.north);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceArray}$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It suffers from the same problem of the answer from David Carlisle. It's more or less nice, but it's not what I wanted. I appreciate the work (this things really take some work! and I always try to learn something from it +1) But meanwhile, I came up with the result I wanted and answer my own post.

Comment: Indeed, this could be automated (I have this in mind). ;-) The advantage of this type of approach is that it produces aligned operators, and `t`.

Comment: @amrsa I did some cosmetic work.

Comment: Yes I suppose my goal became more clear to all of you when I was able to produce my own version (even if mine one is not as good for cases in which the monomials in each line are not consecutive, at least people understood what I wanted). Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This aligns the *t* but I can't say I like the result much, you could add even more `&` and align the +/- as well but not aligning the terms might be more readable

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{-1}
f(t)
&= &(&t + 1)^4 - &(&t + 1)^3  && + &2(&t + 1) + &1\\
&= &&t^4  &+4&t^3 + &6&t^2 + &4&t + &1\\
&  && &-&t^3  - &3&t^2 - &3&t - &1\\
&  & & & & & & + &2&t + &2\\
&  & & & & & & & &   + &1
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh and add some `{}` back to get relation spacing

Comment: Yes, maybe it's not really possible to do what I wanted. This is what I meant with "I understand that this is because I don't have enough `&` in the first line, but it seems impossible to put some in the exact location to have this right." Good (+1), but not good enough.

Comment: I don't know if it could be done with some kind of nested alignment? I think I'm gonna try that.

Comment: @amrsa you could put `&` in exact locations but I could not guess where exactly you want alignment and I don't think the alignment is helping. You could insert `&` betwen every character if you really wanted

Comment: Yes, I understand. And maybe I could reproduce exactly what I want, but it would be extremely confusing and not reusable for other situations.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a version I came up with.

```
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= (t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 +2(t + 1) + 1\\
&
\begin{aligned}
&={} &t^4 &{}+{} &4t^3 &{}+{} &6t^2 &{}+{} &4t &{}+{} &1\\
&    &    &{}-{} &t^3  &{}-{} &3t^2 &{}-{} &3t &{}-{} &1\\
&    &    &      &     &      &     &{}+{} &2t &{}+{} &2\\
&    &    &      &     &      &     &      &   &{}+{} &1
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

Notice I changed from `alignat` to `aligned`.
Apparently, `alignat` doesn't work with nested alignment.
This gives the following result
[image]

It's still not perfect because the lines starting at the second have too much space between the monomials.
I'd prefer to somewhat smash those spaces because they don't have to align with the first in the right side (and actually they don't; they even stretch too much for that), but I don't know how to do it.

---

**Edit.**
I finally got it:

```
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= (t + 1)^4 - (t + 1)^3 +2(t + 1) + 1\\
&
\begin{aligned}
{}= t^4 + 4t^3 + 6t^2 + 4t + 1&\\
{}- t^3  - 3t^2 - 3t - 1&\\
{}+ 2t + 2&\\
{}+ 1&\\
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
```

gives the following
[image]
which was what I wanted!

Comment: I think it's a bit unfortunate, visually speaking, that the `+` symbols that start the final two lines are treated as unary instead of as binary operators. Anyway, +1.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I also just noticed that

Comment: It could be fixed readily by prefixing `{}` to the `+` symbols in question.

Comment: @Mico Ah, ok, thanks. And there's a missing minus at the beginning of the third line. I'll edit it.